# Question on Properties of maximal normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I found a theorem in my Lecture notes where the proof was left for practice

Let ${ H }_{ 1 },{ K }_{ 1 }$ be two maximal normal subgroups, ${ H }_{ 1 }\neq { K }_{ 1 }$, with the intersection $X={ H }_{ 1 }\cap { K }_{ 1 }$

Show that $X\lhd G\quad G={ H }_{ 1 }{ K }_{ 1 }$ holds.

I already showed that X is a normal subgroup which is fairly easy but i dont know how to show that $G={ H }_{ 1 }{ K }_{ 1 }$ since the only case known to me for $G={ H }_{ 1 }{ K }_{ 1 }$ to be true is if their intersection is trivial

Comment: Note $HK$ is a (normal) subgroup, and it is in between $H$ and $G$ (and also in between $K$ and $G$).

Comment: i think $H_1 K_1 $ is referring to the set of all $h_1*k_1$, $h_1 \in H_1, k_1 \in K_1$ and not their *direct* product (for this you would also require that their intersection is empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show the product of 2 normal subgroups is itself a normal subgroup, then use the maximality of $H_1$ and $K_1$, as well as the fact they dont coincide to finish the proof.